# How to fix my Tic Tac Toe game logical error

Tags: c, loops

I wrote a Tic Tac Toe code which uses three functions. But it isn't stopping even when the conditions are met. I tried on multiple compilers like online gdb, and others online along with VS Code.

I made a for loop that runs the program like 8 times because the winner will be declared before that if any winner comes out. Else it will declare a draw. But the draw condition isn't working properly.

```
 //tic tac toe multiplayer mode
#include<stdio.h>

void player1(char user1, char arr[][3]);
void player2(char user2, char arr[][3]);
int checkwinner( char arr[][3], char user1, char user2);
int main(){
char user1='x',user2='0';
char arr[][3]={  {'1','2','3',},
                 {'4','5','6'},
                 {'7','8','9'}
              };
printf("user1 is x and user2 is 0.\ndecide who wants to be user1.\nx plays first\n");
int i=0,y=0;
int a=0,b=0;
for(a=0;a<3;a++){            
        for(b=0;b<3;b++){
            printf("%c ",arr[a][b]);
        }printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
 for(i=0;i<8;i++){

    player1(user1,arr);          //goto line 64
    for(a=0;a<3;a++){             //print array
        for(b=0;b<3;b++){
            printf(" %c ",arr[a][b]);
        }printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");


    y=checkwinner(arr, user1, user2);         // check if winner is found  @line 130
    if(y==1){
        printf("user1 wins\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(y==2){
        printf("user2 wins\n");
        return 0;
    } 


player2(user2,arr);                           
    for(a=0;a<3;a++){
        for(b=0;b<3;b++){
            printf( "%c ",arr[a][b]);
        }printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");


    y=checkwinner(arr, user1, user2);           //check for winner @line 130
    if(y==1){
        printf("user1 wins\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(y==2){
        printf("user2 wins\n");
        return 0;
    } 
     
}                                                
if(y==0){
        printf("draw\n");
    }

return 0;
}



void player1(char user1, char arr[][3]){
printf("user1 enter location. please donot select already used location\n");
int location;
scanf("%d",&location);
if((arr[0][0]!='x' && arr[0][0]!='0' ) &&(location==1)){     
   arr[0][0]='x';                                            
}
if((arr[0][1]!='x' && arr[0][1]!='0' ) &&(location==2)){
   arr[0][1]='x';
}
if((arr[0][2]!='x' && arr[0][2]!='0' ) &&(location==3)){
   arr[0][2]='x';
}
if((arr[1][0]!='x' && arr[1][0]!='0' ) &&(location==4)){
   arr[1][0]='x';
}
if((arr[1][1]!='x' && arr[1][1]!='0' ) &&(location==5)){
   arr[1][1]='x';
}
if((arr[1][2]!='x' && arr[1][2]!='0' ) &&(location==6)){
   arr[1][2]='x';
}
if((arr[2][0]!='x' && arr[2][0]!='0' ) &&(location==7)){
   arr[2][0]='x';
}
if((arr[2][1]!='x' && arr[2][1]!='0' ) &&(location==8)){
   arr[2][1]='x';
}
if((arr[2][2]!='x' && arr[2][2]!='0' ) &&(location==9)){
   arr[2][2]='x';
}
}



void player2(char user2, char arr[][3]){
printf("user2 enter location.please donot select already used location\n");
int location;
scanf("%d",&location);
if((arr[0][0]!='x' && arr[0][0]!='0' ) &&(location==1)){          
   arr[0][0]='0';                                                
}
if((arr[0][1]!='x' && arr[0][1]!='0' ) &&(location==2)){
   arr[0][1]='0';
}
if((arr[0][2]!='x' && arr[0][2]!='0' ) &&(location==3)){
   arr[0][2]='0';
}
if((arr[1][0]!='x' && arr[1][0]!='0' ) &&(location==4)){
   arr[1][0]='0';
}
if((arr[1][1]!='x' && arr[1][1]!='0' ) &&(location==5)){
   arr[1][1]='0';
}
if((arr[1][2]!='x' && arr[1][2]!='0' ) &&(location==6)){
   arr[1][2]='0';
}
if((arr[2][0]!='x' && arr[2][0]!='0' ) &&(location==7)){
   arr[2][0]='0';
}
if((arr[2][1]!='x' && arr[2][1]!='0' ) &&(location==8)){
   arr[2][1]='0';
}
if((arr[2][2]!='x' && arr[2][2]!='0' ) &&(location==9)){
   arr[2][2]='0';
}
}



int checkwinner( char arr[][3], char user1, char user2){
int y=0;                                    
     if( (arr[0][0] ==arr[0][1])&& (arr[0][0]==arr[0][2]) ){       
         if(arr[0][0]==user1){                                                             
             y=1;                                                                          
             return y;                                                                      
         }                                                                                 
         else{                                                                      
              y=2;                                                    
              return y;                                                                
         }                                                                                       
     }                                                                                      
     else if((arr[1][0] ==arr[1][1]) && ( arr[1][0] ==arr[1][2]) ){
         if(arr[1][0]  ==user1){
             y=1;
             return y;
         }
         else{
              y=2;
              return y;
         }
     }
     else if( (arr[2][0] ==arr[2][1])&& ( arr[2][0]==arr[2][2])){
         if(arr[2][0] ==user1){
             y=1;
             return y;
         }
         else{
              y=2;
              return y;
         }
     }
     else if((arr[0][0] ==arr[1][0] )&& ( arr[0][0]==arr[2][0]) ){
         if(arr[0][0] ==user1){
              y=1;
             return y;
         }
         else{
             y=2;
              return y;
         }
     }
     else if( (arr[0][1] ==arr[1][1])&& ( arr[0][1]==arr[2][1])){
         if(arr[0][1] ==user1){
               y=1;
             return y;
         }
         else{
              y=2;
              return y;
         }
     }
     else if((arr[0][2] ==arr[1][2])&& ( arr[0][2]==arr[2][2]) ){
         if(arr[0][2] ==user1){
             y=1;
             return y;
         }
         else{
              y=2;
              return y;
         }
     }
     else if( (arr[0][0] ==arr[1][1]) && ( arr[0][0]==arr[2][2]) ){
         if(arr[0][0] ==user1){
              y=1;
             return y;
         }
         else{
               y=2;
              return y;
         }
     }
     else if((arr[0][2] ==arr[1][1])&& ( arr[0][2]==arr[2][0])){
         if(arr[0][2] ==user1){
             y=1;
             return y;
         }
         else{
              y=2;
              return y;
         }
     }
     y=0;
     return y;
}
```

Comment: Why are you initialising `y=0` right before the `return y` statement?

Comment: Get rid of all the duplicated code to print the board and read player input.  That's what subroutines are for.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following minor logic problems with the code:

1. As @Deepika suggested, the code `y=0;` at the end defeats all logic in function `checkwinner()` so remove it.
2. The function `checkwinner()` does not check for the draw state, and if true requires a return value for draw. I suggest adding logic for the draw state and return 3=draw.
3. Inside the `for(i=0;i<8;i++){` requires a check for the draw state, and if so then needs to re-initialize variables (i.e., the game array) and print the array to start a fresh game. As @stark mentioned, no need to duplicate code to print the array, make it a function call. While on this subject, the routines `player1()` and `player2()` could also be combined into a single function.

Comment: Maybe intentionally, maybe not. This nicely fits https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Good mention @Yunnosch. I though of this while removing all my suggested code corrections and only leaving a summary of my findings.

Comment: So you would be prepared for more steps. Let's see whether OP earns them.